# jPlayer not advancing to next track when tab is not active in Safari

Tags: safari, tabs, focus, jplayer

For some reason with Safari, but not other browsers, a jPlayer playlist doesn't advance to the next track when the tab is not in focus, i.e. is not the current tab.   It simply pauses at the end of the track. This is an issue that others have observed too, and I am wondering if there is a solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working in the latest version of Safari, i.e. Safari 6.0